# JavaScript counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everytime a specific action is made in JavaScript for example this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#typing').keyup(function () {
     switch($(this).val()) {
       case 'containment':
// HERE
break;
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

inside the //HERE would be where the 'counter' was made. Then add 1 everytime the case 'containment' is run if it's not already run. So if I run containment  case once.. it adds. If I run it again.. it will not -- see what I am talking about?

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is? Wouldn't you simply increase a variable for a counter function?

Comment: @Pekka: I believe the question is "see what I am talking about?"

Comment: Haha I just want a variable to increase by ONE number everytime a case statement is run once.

Comment: Why do you need a counter?  From your question, all I gather is that you want to run the statement only once.  So, why do you need a counter?

Comment: I want to see how many case statements were run out of all available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the counter before the counting starts. Then you can add to it later, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;  //(or any number you need)
$(function() {
    $('#typing').keyup(function () {
     switch($(this).val()) {
       case 'containment':
          count++;
break;
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I am JavaScript newb. How would I display the counter on a web page? :P

Comment: If you have a <span> or <div> that you would want to show the counter in it, like this: `<span id="counter"></span>` you can insert the counter (and even update it when it changes) by putting `$('#counter').text(count);` directly below the `count++;` rule

Comment: Ok cool. How would I divide the counter by a certain number... let's say.. 43 and make it round like 00.00% that?

Comment: This is not working:
     if(moviesRun) {
         count++;
         newPercent = count/34;
         $('#counter').text(newPercent);
         moviesRun = false;
         }

Comment: Ok whoops - it works now. But now I get: 0.03333333333333333% How do I round that to like 00.03%?

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var shouldRunContainment = true;

$(function() {
    $('#typing').keyup(function () {
     switch($(this).val()) {
       case 'containment':
       if(shouldRunContainment) {
         shouldRunContainment = false;
         // Run containment
       }
       break;
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's one way -- but waht about the counter? Could be handled via cookies?

Comment: What exactly do you want to count?

Comment: A simple variable. I want to count how many 'first-runs- of a case was initiated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a counter you can add/remove a class from `$('#typing')`.

For example:

```
var count = 0;
$('#typing').keyup(function () {
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'containment':
        // Will only run if the element does NOT have the containment class
        if(!$(this).hasClass('containment'){
            // Add containment class
            $(this).addClass('containment');
            // Counter
            count++;
        }
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Where does the counter fit in all of this?